# Condition for non-negative Fourier transform: $\mathcal{F} \exp(-|x|^a)(|x|^a\log(x)+\delta) \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, positive-definite

I am looking for $\delta>0$, such that Fourier transform of $\exp(-|x|^a)(|x|^a\log(x)+\delta)$, $a \in (1,2)$ is non-negative. I have tried to evaluate the integral  for $a=2$. I failed to arrive at an analytical expression to be of any use. I could prove that such $\delta$ exists, again for $a=2$ only

Comment: Did you mean $\log |x|$, for $a=2$ it reduces to the decay of the Fourier transform of $\exp(-x^2) x^2\log |x|$ how did you manage it.

Comment: Basically Fourier transform is   
\\
&&{1\over 8\sqrt{2}}\{  2\gamma\exp(-\omega^2/4)(\omega^2-2)+ 8 \delta\exp\left(-{\omega^2\over 4}\right)\\
&& +\int_{1}^{+\infty} { \exp\{-(\omega-x)^2/4\}\{(\omega-x)^2-2\}   +  \exp\{-(\omega+x)^2/4\}\{(\omega+x)^2-2\}   \over x} dx        \\
&& + \int_{-1}^{+1} {\exp\{-(\omega-x)^2/4\}\{(\omega-x)^2-2\}    -  \exp(-\omega^2/4)(\omega^2-2)   \over |x|} dx      \} .   I do not have a closed form expression, but I can show it is bounded and positive when \omega \to 0

Comment: The case $a=1$ is doable because $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}e^{-2i\pi xt} x\log x dx=\frac{d}{db}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}e^{-2i\pi xt} x^b dx|_{b=1}=\frac{d}{db}(1+2i\pi t)^{-b-1}\Gamma(b+1)|_{b=1}$$

Comment: I believe it should be a rational function for a=1. think about it is a derivative of Fourier of exp(-x^a) with respect to a. We can exchange integration and derivative

Comment: My comment shows there is a $\log(1+2i\pi t)$ coming in. My formula follows easily for $1+2i\pi t >0$ and it stays true for $\Re(1+2i\pi t) >0$ by analytic continuation.

Comment: @reuns I see it now, I need arbitrary a though, a\in(1,2)

Comment: @reuns you Fourier transform is incorrect, it should be cos not \exp(-2i\pi), the range is from 0 to \infty.

Comment: Sure take the real part.. I'm saying for $a=1$ there is a closed-form so the existence of $\delta$ can be checked easily.

Comment: @reuns I have a solutions for a<=1 anyways, need one for 1<a<2